# Opening login page on two tab in browser and login in by one after another, getting "The page isn't redirecting properly" in second tab login time

Tags: c#, asp.net

visible

I am getting the following error in the page and the page isn't redirecting properly  .

> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete.

This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

Error is generated when I open login page on two tab of same browser
and logging in by first tab and when I am try to logging in second
tab that time i am getting this error message.

Can someone help me to fix this error? i want to solve this error by asp.net, c#.

Comment: Good formatting is always your friend! Learn it.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem there is no need to delete all of your cookies, simply delete the ones associated with your google and youtube accounts. **Here's how:**

```
- Click Tools/Options/Privacy

- Click "Remove Individual Cookies"

- In the Cookies Window type "accounts" (no quotes) into the Search box
```

Comment: i want to know how to handle in asp.net, c# . even it this method is not working. i have tried.